# I did something with coloring the borders of the chessboard and now I can't have coordinates in any of my boards

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, chessboard, skak

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pgf=false]{chessboard}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=mashriq,numerals=arabic]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{NotoSans-Regular}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.6]{Amiri}
%\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
%\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

\setRTL


\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
الفصل الخامس التراكيب
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
1.  الأفكار والدوافع التراكبية
\\
\\
\\
نحن نعرف مسبقاً أن التراكيب هي الاسم المُعطى للفعل المنسق لبعض القطع، يأخذ شكل تفريع قسري يتضمن التضحية ببعض القطع، تكون نتيجته تعويل اللاعب الحصول على بعض المنافع من شكل ما. هدف التركيب قد يكون هو إماتة الخصم أو ربح القطع، وفي بعض الأحيان انقاذ اللاعب من الخسارة بالوصول إلى الكش المكرر أو خنق الملك. وفي أحيان أخرى فإن التركيب قد يلاحق أهدافاً أخرى ككسر تشكيل بيادق الخصم، أو السيطرة على بعض المربعات أو الخطوط لقطعك، أو مبادلة القطع الناشطة لخصمك، وهكذا. في هذه الحالات الأخيرة، وبمساعدة التركيب، فأنت تحصل على ما يعرف كأصول موضعية وهي الأفضلية في تموضع قطعك.
\\
\\
\\
أكثر ما يميز التركيب هو الطبيعة القسرية للحركات التي تشكله، وأيضاً في معظم الحالات فجائيتها (التضحية!) التي تفاجئنا بقوة (وتجد تبريرها) عندما تبلغ أوجها، الذروة التي هي جوهر التركيب.
\\
\\
\\
على الرغم من أن التركيب يتبع منطقياً الوضع الموجود على الرقعة، فإن الطبيعة الاستثنائية لبعض الحركات (التضحية بالقطع) تُوقع الفوضى، إذا جاز التعبير، في التدفق الطبيعي للدور، وتحوله على نحو مفاجئ إلى مسار جديد (كقفزة أو انفجار). والنتيجة هي علاقات متبادلة مختلفة للقوات على الرقعة وإطار جديد للصراع.
\\
\\
\\
في الوضعيات المعطاة في هذا الفصل، حاول أن تجد التركيب بنفسك كل مرة قبل أن تتابع القراءة.
\twocolumn
\columnsep=2cm
\setLTR
\newgame
\chessboard[pgf=false]
\begin{center}
265

\newgame

\fenboard{3k2r1/3b4/R7/3NKP2/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard
%\showboard

\end{center}


\begin{center}
265

\newgame

\fenboard{3k2r1/3b4/R7/3NKP2/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard[showmover=true,label=true,hlabelwidth=2ex,labelfontsize=22,pgf=false]
%\showboard

\end{center}

\begin{center}
266

\newgame

\fenboard{r2qkb1r/ppp2ppp/8/4p3/3nP3/2Q5/PPP2PPP/R1B1K1NR b  KQkq - 1 2}
\chessboard[showmover=true,marginwidth=0.5cm,borderwidth=0.1cm,bordercolor=teal]
%\showboard


\end{center}

\begin{center}
267
\newgame

\fenboard{3k4/1p6/5q2/4n1NP/PK2Q3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1}
\chessboard[showmover=true]
%\showboard
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

polyglossia redefines \arabic - imho a rather unfriendly act - but you can reset the labels like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=mashriq,numerals=arabic]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{NotoSans-Regular}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.6]{Amiri}
\setchessboard{labelfont=\englishfont,
               hlabelformat={\number\value{ranklabel}},
               vlabelformat=\latinalph{filelabel},
               }
\begin{document}
الفصل 

\setLTR
\newgame
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't work I'm trying to build the whole thong using babel again No polyglossia this time

Comment: It worked for me on a current texlive 2020.